# Dynamically change field label on Gravity Forms form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a form using Gravity Forms in Wordpress. The first question is:

"What equipment was used?" - This is a `single line text` field.

The user is required to give this answer.

Later on in the form I would like to ask:

"What was the visual condition of the `{answer from first question here}`"

Is there a way for me to put the answer from the first question between the curly braces of the later question in the field label?

Answer (score 1):

Populate Anything supports this with a feature called Live Merge Tags:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/#live-merge-tags

Your configuration might look something like this:

[image]